# Pandas Extract Number from String

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['1a',np.nan,'10a','100b','0b'],
                   })
df

    A
0   1a
1   NaN
2   10a
3   100b
4   0b
```

I'd like to extract the numbers from each cell (where they exist).
The desired result is:

```
    A
0   1
1   NaN
2   10
3   100
4   0
```

I know it can be done with `str.extract`, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Give it a regex capture group:

```
df.A.str.extract('(\d+)')
```

Gives you:

```
0      1
1    NaN
2     10
3    100
4      0
Name: A, dtype: object
```

---

`(\d+)` is a regex capturing group, and `\d+` specifies a regex pattern that matches only digits. Note that this will only work for whole numbers and not floats.

Comment: how could I do it when there is a comma like : `6,000 a`

Comment: @StevenG strip out commas first?

Comment: As of 2020, this codes gives a FutureWarning.  You get around it by adding the parameter `expand=False` to the `extract`

Comment: This doesn't work if there is number after alphabets

Comment: This does not work for my column with number and units: `0.7 mg `

Comment: Great answer, but would have been even greater if it was explained what ```'(\d+)'``` does. In the regular expression ```\d``` stands for "any digit" and ```+``` stands for "one or more". So all digits are extracted, whereas with ```str.replace('\d+', '')``` all digits are removed.

Answer (score 9):

To answer @Steven G 's question in the comment above, this should work:

```
df.A.str.extract('(^\d*)')
```

Answer (score 8):

U can replace your column with your result using "assign" function:

```
df = df.assign(A = lambda x: x['A'].str.extract('(\d+)'))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have cases where you have multiple disjoint sets of digits, as in `1a2b3c`, in which you would like to extract `123`, you can do it with `Series.str.replace`:

```py
>>> df
        A
0      1a
1      b2
2    a1b2
3  1a2b3c
>>> df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace('\D+', '')
0      1
1      2
2     12
3    123
```

You could also work this around with `Series.str.extractall` and `groupby` but I think that this one is easier.

Hope this helps!