# Extraction of numeric data from a string

Tags: pandas

```
movies['year'] = movies['title'].str.extract('.*\((.*)\).*', expand=True)
```

In the above line of code please explain the use of every character in the `.*\((.*)\).*`. How it will extract 1995 from Toy Story(1995)?

Comment: That's a regular expression: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions

Comment: You can use regex101 here: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

What you doing above only works as your year is in `()`, for example the below doesn't work:

```
In [98]: pd.Series(["Toy Story 1995"]).str.extract('.*\((.*)\).*', expand=True)                                                   
Out[98]: 
     0
0  NaN

In [99]: pd.Series(["Toy Story (test)"]).str.extract('.*\((.*)\).*', expand=True)                                                 
Out[99]: 
      0
0  test
```

The above is finding all elements between brackets. The `*.` is literally matching all elements, the `/` is escaping the outer `()` and the inner `()` are for specifying the *capturing group* i.e. what pattern.

You probably want to do something as per below, `/d` is short hand for digit `[0-9]` and `{4}` highlights the expected length, so if you know the year format is `yyyy` then could do the below:

```
movies['title'].str.extract('(\d{4})')
```

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683558/pandas-extract-number-from-string) has a more general example using `/d+`