# From a varchar column extract the last numerical digit seperated by '-'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this.

```
COURSE_ID
EX-AAB-5S-102345
EX-A45-5F-143567
INC-AAB-WW-104514
INC-AAB-DE-567431
```

What i am trying is to create a new column COURSE where i will only have the 6digit numerical filed

```
COURSE_ID.            COURSE
EX-AAB-5S-102345.     102345
EX-A45-5F-143567.     143567
INC-AAB-WW-104514.    104514
INC-AAB-DE-567431.    567431
```

Comment: Does this answer your question ? [Pandas Extract Number from String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683558/pandas-extract-number-from-string)

Comment: `df['COURSE']=df['COURSE_ID.'].str.split('-').str[4]`?

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.extract`:

```py
df["COURSE"] = df["COURSE_ID"].str.extract(r'(\d+)$')
```