# How would one extrapolate data from one column of strings and set a value in another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some scraped data from an ecommerce website and that has the package unit count in the name (see example below). I want to take the unit count information from the name and add the number of units as a int into a "Unit" column.  I know I can use `df.loc[product_column].str.contains('10 pk'), unitColumn] = 10`, or even loop through a list that holds sample strings of each unit count. But it becomes a little more cumbersome when your looking at data from 150 stores.

What I'm looking for is a way for python to figure it out automatically and change set the value for with ML. I don't know if it's possible but I'm hoping someone can point me in then right direction.

```
Product name 10 pack
flavor 10 Pack product name
10 pack name
product name flavor 10pk
flavor product name 14Pk
1gx14 Product name
name 2-Pack
2pk different name 
store name 3 pack
product name 5 pack store name
name 5 pack
5 Pack product name
Name 5-pack product name
randome name 5pk product name
name 5pk flavor
6 Pack flavor
flavor 7 pack
prduct name 7 pack 
7pk flavor
pack x2 name
```

I know I can do

```
df.loc[product_column].str.contains('10 pk'), unitColumn] = 10
```

But I'm looking for more of an automated solution.

Comment: What about just [extracting the number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683558/pandas-extract-number-from-string)? There's one case in your example where this may not work (`1gx14 Product name`), but if those are rare, you could fix them by hand or just keep the errors (which you could have anyway using ML).

Comment: Please check [How to make pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this solution:

Put all possibilities in a dictionary.

```
    dfQty={
    2:tuple(['Pack x2', '2-pack', '2pk','2-pack']),
    3: tuple(['3 pack', '3pk']),
    #4: tuple([]),
    5: tuple(['5 pack', '5-pack','5pk']),
    6: tuple(['6 pack']),
    7: tuple(['7 pack', '7pk']),
    #8: tuple([]),
    #9: tuple([]),
    10: tuple(['10pk','10 Pack']),
    #11: tuple([]),
    #12: tuple([]),
    #13: tuple([]),
    14: tuple(['14pk','1gx14']) 
}
```

Then I looped through the dictionary and used str.containes(item) to change value.

```
for key, value in dfQty.items():
       for item in value:
            #for ind, row in df.iterrows()
        df2.loc[df2['Product'].str.contains(item, case=False, na=False), 'Units'] = key
```

Import things I realized while doing this are:

1. It's important for my dictionary items to be wrapped in a tuple; otherwise, I get an unhashable error.
2. I had to comment out key with no values.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37683738/15032126) to your case were a number that's followed by the letter `g` is not a quantity, you can do

```
df['Package_unit_count'] = df['Product'].str.extract('(\d+)[^g]')
```

| index | Product | Package_unit_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Product name 10 pack | 10 |
| 1 | flavor 10 Pack product name | 10 |
| 2 | 10 pack name | 10 |
| 3 | product name flavor 10pk | 10 |
| 4 | flavor product name 14Pk | 14 |
| 5 | 1gx14 Product name | 14 |
| 6 | name 2-Pack | 2 |
| 7 | 2pk different name | 2 |
| 8 | store name 3 pack | 3 |
| 9 | product name 5 pack store name | 5 |
| 10 | name 5 pack | 5 |
| 11 | 5 Pack product name | 5 |
| 12 | Name 5-pack product name | 5 |
| 13 | randome name 5pk product name | 5 |
| 14 | name 5pk flavor | 5 |
| 15 | 6 Pack flavor | 6 |
| 16 | flavor 7 pack | 7 |
| 17 | prduct name 7 pack | 7 |
| 18 | 7pk flavor | 7 |
| 19 | pack x2 name | 2 |